# Unable to process large files in camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to do simple transformation on a Csv file.But my programm is getting stuck and not giving any output and on console its printing something like below.

```
22:38:02.001 [main] INFO  o.a.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.15.2 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down
22:38:02.135 [main] INFO  o.a.c.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 300 seconds)
22:38:02.167 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.i.DefaultExecutorServiceManager - Created new ThreadPool for source: org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy@65ead16a with name: ShutdownTask. -> org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.RejectableThreadPoolExecutor@52c0a65f[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0][ShutdownTask]
22:38:02.173 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - ShutdownTask] DEBUG o.a.c.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - There are 1 routes to shutdown
22:38:02.177 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - ShutdownTask] DEBUG o.a.c.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Route: route1 suspended and shutdown deferred, was consuming from: Endpoint[file:///home/cloudera/Desktop/camelinput/?delay=15m&noop=true]
22:38:02.177 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - ShutdownTask] INFO  o.a.c.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Waiting as there are still 2 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 300 seconds.
22:38:02.179 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - ShutdownTask] DEBUG o.a.c.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - There are 1 inflight exchanges:
    InflightExchange: [exchangeId=ID-quickstart-cloudera-40574-1441345060577-0-2, fromRouteId=route1, routeId=route1, nodeId=unmarshal1, elapsed=10787, duration=10791]
22:38:05.436 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - ShutdownTask] INFO  o.a.c.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Waiting as there are still 2 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 299 seconds.
22:38:05.437 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - ShutdownTask] DEBUG o.a.c.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - There are 1 inflight exchanges:
    InflightExchange: [exchangeId=ID-quickstart-cloudera-40574-1441345060577-0-2, fromRouteId=route1, routeId=route1, nodeId=unmarshal1, elapsed=14045, duration=14049]
22:38:08.201 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - ShutdownTask] INFO  o.a.c.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Waiting as there are still 2 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 298 seconds.
22:38:08.202 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - ShutdownTask] DEBUG o.a.c.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - There are 1 inflight exchanges:
    InflightExchange: [exchangeId=ID-quickstart-cloudera-40574-1441345060577-0-2, fromRouteId=route1, routeId=route1, nodeId=unmarshal1, elapsed=16810, duration=16814]
```

Actually the same program worked for small file but when I try to do with large file I am getting this issue.I think it may problem with Threads .Please Help me out to figure out the issue.

Following is my Program

*Main Class*

```
    TestRouter myRoute = new TestRouter();

    HDFSTransfer hdfsTransfer = new HDFSTransfer();
    String copy = hdfsTransfer.copyToLocal(
            "hdfs://localhost:8020", 
            "/user/cloudera/input/CamelTestIn.csv", 
            "/home/cloudera/Desktop/camelinput/");
    boolean flag = false;
    if ("SUCCESS".equals(copy)) {
        myContext.addRoutes(myRoute);

        // Launching the context
        myContext.start();

        // Pausing to let the route do its work
        Thread.sleep(10000);

        myContext.stop();
        flag = true;
    }
    if (flag) {
        hdfsTransfer.moveFile(
            "hdfs://localhost:8020", 
            "file:/home/cloudera/Desktop/camelout/out.csv", 
            "/user/cloudera/output/");
    }
```

*RouterBuilder Class*

```
    {
        CsvDataFormat csv = new CsvDataFormat();

        from("file:/home/cloudera/Desktop/camelinput/?noop=true&delay=15m")

                .unmarshal(csv)
                .convertBodyTo(List.class)
                .process(new Processor() {

                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange msg) throws Exception {
                        List<List<String>> data = (List<List<String>>) msg.getIn().getBody();
                        for (List<String> line : data) {
                            // Checks if column two contains text STANDARD
                            // and alters its value to DELUXE.
                            // System.out.println("line "+line);
                        /*
                            if("Aug-04".equalsIgnoreCase(line.get(6))){
                            line.set(6, "04-August");}
                         */

                        }
                    }
                }).marshal(csv)

                .to("file:/home/cloudera/Desktop/camelout/?fileName=out.csv")

                .log("done.").end();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a bigger file then you need to sleep for longer than 10 seconds to let it have time to process the file.

Also mind that your current route reads the file into memory when means you can run out of memory if the file is very big.

See the `lazyLoad` option on: http://camel.apache.org/csv.html

Also if all your route is doing is to change some text in a big file, then there is better and faster ways doing that than maybe a Camel route.

Comment: Hi @Claus Ibsen ,Thanks for your reply.As you said I increased the sleep time and as you said it lead to out of memory problem .Then what is simple and Exact solution.Please help me out.